# get All Parents with no children or if there are children, get the latest child

Tags: sql

I have below table orders . `orderId` is the primary key and `parentOrderId` is the column that represents if this order has parent order .

ex: 1,2,3,4 do not have parent orders. 5,6,7,8 have parent orders.

```
+--------------------+----------------------+
|          order_id   | parent_order_id     |
+--------------------+----------------------+
|                  1 |                  null|
|                  2 |                  null|
|                  3 |                  null|
|                  4 |                  null|
|                  5 |                    1 |
|                  6 |                    2 |
|                  7 |                    3 |
|                  8 |                    3 |
+--------------------+----------------------+



I need to query all Parents with no children or if there are children only get the latest child. 
The result I need is : 4,5,6,8
   4 because it has no children and should be returned.
   5 because it is the only child of 1.
   6 because that is the only child of 2.
   8 because 3 has 2 children(7,8) and I need to return latest child. Pick max of orderId's.
```

**What I tried :**

```
SELECT
  MAX(order_id)
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  parent_order_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  parent_order_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
  order_id
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  parent_order_id IS NULL
MINUS
SELECT
  parent_order_id
FROM
  orders;
```

**What I am looking for :**

The above query returns 4,5,6,8 . The problem is I am feeding this query into IN clause and oracle has 1000 limit for IN clause. i am trying to see if there is a better way to approach this problem using joins.
**update :**
Joins will help me retrieve all the columns in order table instead of just id's , for the sake of simplicity i just included two columns, there are more in the table. right now i am fetching id's first and feeding them in clause in another query to get all columns that match those id's.

I am also looking for sql that is not vendor specific.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The 1,000 limit is for a [expression lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Expression-Lists.html), i.e. fixed lists of values; if you are using a subquery directly (i.e. `... in (SELECT ... UNION ALL ... MINUS... FROM orders)` then there isn't a limit on how many rows the subquery can return. There may well be better ways of doing this, but you may be starting from an incorrect understanding.

Comment: @alex poole thanks for your response .  The way our application is designed i had to do two separate queries one to get all valid id's and use that list in the in clause to get all the details for those ids . The other alternative i am thinking of is to batch 1000 id's at a time and do "in(first set of 1000 id's) or in(second set of 1000 id's) ......so on " . not sure if that is the right way.

Comment: Why is `5` not in the desired results? It is the only child of `1`. Then - separately - if a parent has more than one child, how do you define **latest**? Latest, by what measure? Simply in alphabetical (or perhaps numerical) order of their label, so that 8 > 7 (or as strings '8' > '7') means that 8 is "latest"? That is pretty odd; is there an additional column by which you order the children, if there is more than one? Also: does your table only have parents and children, or can the chains have three or more "generations"?

Comment: Also, your discussion of "more than 1000 results" and "using joins" etc. makes no sense. If you do what you are doing now, saving the results and then hard-coding them into an IN clause, how does that change depending on what query produces the more than 1000 results? Wouldn't you have exactly the same problem, regardless of what query produces the results, whether it uses `union all`, a join, or a hierarchical query (perhaps the best choice)? The solution is to modify your application, so that everything you need is done in a single query.

Comment: Otherwise you must create a temporary table, save the results of the first query to it, and select from the temp table for the `IN` condition. But this is a pretty lame solution, compared to the correct answer, which is to get everything in a single query.

Comment: @mathguy thans for pointing that out , i updated my question. By latest i mean max value of order id, in this case max(7,8) which results to 8.  No a child cannot have another child, only parent can have multiple children.

Comment: @mathguy i updated my question on why joins will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP explained in a comment to my other Answer that he needs a query that uses standard SQL features as much as possible. This rules out `connect by` queries, and also facilities as simple as `nvl()`.

The query below gets the same result. It is less general, but it will work for the OP's problem (where there are only parents and children, never "third generation" nodes).

Like my other Answer, it is written so that all columns from the original table (or some relevant subset) can be selected. This is best done with analytic functions, as I did in the other Answer as well.

```
with
  orders_table (order_id, parent_order_id) as (
    select 1, null from dual union all
    select 2, null from dual union all
    select 3, null from dual union all
    select 4, null from dual union all
    select 5, 1    from dual union all
    select 6, 2    from dual union all
    select 7, 3    from dual union all
    select 8, 3    from dual
  )
select order_id, parent_order_id
from   (
         select o.* 
              , max(order_id) over 
                     (partition by coalesce(parent_order_id, order_id)) as max_id
         from   orders_table o
       )
where order_id = max_id
;
```

Comment: this modified version using group by also works :  select * 
from  orders_table where order_id in (
         select  max(order_id)               
         from   orders_table 
         group by coalesce(parent_order_id, order_id)
       );

Comment: @rohith - OK, but in your query you read the data from the table twice. Analytic functions were introduced with the specific goal of avoiding such need - to read data more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve this problem, using a `connect by` query (which is, in fact, a form of join - optimized for hierarchical data, like yours). The WITH clause is not part of the solution, it is there only to simulate your inputs. Use your actual table and column names.

Note that I also get the row with `order_id = 5` in the results (I asked about that in my comments, you answered other questions but not this one).

This shows how to get ALL the columns you need in one pass.

```
with
  orders_table (order_id, parent_order_id) as (
    select 1, null from dual union all
    select 2, null from dual union all
    select 3, null from dual union all
    select 4, null from dual union all
    select 5, 1    from dual union all
    select 6, 2    from dual union all
    select 7, 3    from dual union all
    select 8, 3    from dual
  )
select order_id, parent_order_id
from   (
         select     o.*
              ,     max(order_id)
                        over (partition by connect_by_root order_id) as max_id
         from       orders_table o
         where      connect_by_isleaf = 1
         start with parent_order_id is null
         connect by parent_order_id = prior order_id
       )
where  order_id = max_id
;

ORDER_ID  PARENT_ORDER_ID
--------  ---------------
       5                1
       6                2
       8                3
       4
```

Comment: thank you @mathguy . Looks like a solution without "connect by" is not possible ? The reason i ask is i need to translate this above query into query dsl jpa query, i may not be able to do that because this is oracle specific.

Comment: Absolutely it is possible to rewrite this using join syntax. I will propose one way when I have time. However, such restrictions should always be part of your question; right now there's nothing about it in your original post, and the tags are simply `sql` and `oracle` - no indication that an Oracle solution will **not** work for you.

Comment: agree, my fault . but i will keep that in mind. I was under the impression that i should be able to translate any sql query, but ignored the fact that queries can be vendor specific(oracle in this case). really appreciate your response, thank you.